# Doctrine use multiple column types -- array and string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I use Doctrine ORM with Symfony and one of my entities is a Setting object. Inside, the value key can be either a string or array, with lifecycle callbacks to adjust accordingly. I've run into a problem where JMS Serializer gets confused because the value key (array) doesn't match the column type (text). Is there a way for these two to coexist? Can I tell Doctrine to fall back to text if the content is not an array? It doesn't use Doctrine, but WordPress handles this sort of thing in the options table.

**EDIT**
Here is some of the code so far. It works properly when held in objects but fails when JMS Serializer has to serialize it for an API request.

Column definition

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
* @Expose
*/
protected $value;
```

Custom handler for un/serializing column as needed

```
 /**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 * Serialize, if necessary
 */
 public function serializeSetting() {
    if (is_array($this->getValue())) {
        $this->setValue(serialize($this->getValue()));
    }
 }

 /**
 * @ORM\postLoad
 * Unserialize, if necessary
 */
 public function unserializeSetting() {
     $unserialized = @unserialize($this->getValue());
     if ($unserialized !== false)
        $this->setValue($unserialized);
 }
```

Comment: Might help if you post the code you have so far.

Comment: Your PHPDoc for `serializeSetting` is wrong. Replace `/*` with `/**`.

Comment: The annotation on a property for the serializer can't have logic, but you can have the serializer set/get it with an accessor that has the logic.